# Dual-boot not working

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu in my notebook, used it by the first time for a few hours and then turned off the computer. But when I turned it on again, my Windows loaded automatically.
In the System Setup, I found this as boot order:

```
#1: Windows Boot Manager
#2: ubuntu
#3: UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe Family Controller
#4: UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe Family Controller
#5: ubuntu
```

previous experiences in my life teached me to never change the system setup without knowing what I'm doing (yeah, I got a pretty angry brother when I was a kid), so I want to know what I should put first in the order.
My notebook is a 3 months old Dell Inspiron 14r.

Comment: It seems that Ubuntu didn't replace boot loader with its own one, if you do this intentionally , you have to repair the Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue with booting, please try the following,

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair

Once you are done with the above restart the machine and check.

Comment: I said I can't choose the boot, it initialize Windows automatically, how would I get to Ubuntu to type these commands?

Comment: Press function key(F8)(it varies on the brand) to manually select the Operating System. It will prompt two operating system select Ubuntu and try.